# Differential of Sum of Two Functions is Sum of Differentials

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold and $f, g:M\to \mathbf R^n$ be smooth functions on $M$. Let $p$ be a point on $M$.

> I want to show that $d(f+g)_p=df_p+dg_p$ without passing to a chart about $p$.

For an arbitrary derivation $X\in T_pM$, we need to show that $d(f+g)_pX=df_pX+dg_pX$. This amounts to showing that for an arbitrary smooth map $\xi:\mathbf R^n\to \mathbf R$, we have
$$X(\xi\circ(f+g))=X(\xi\circ f)+X(\xi\circ g)$$

This is clearly true if $\xi$ is linear. But I am not able to show this for a general $\xi$.

Comment: I don't see the reason to introduce $\xi.$ It is $df_p X=X(f).$ So, you only need to show that $X(f+g)=X(f)+X(g),$ which should be easy.

Comment: @mfl I have edited the question to have $\xi$ more relevant.

Comment: It doesn't hold for a general function $\xi.$ Consider $f(x,y)=x^2,g(x,y)=y^2$ and $\xi(t)=e^t.$ Then, $$2xe^{x^2+y^2}=\partial_x(e^{x^2+y^2})=\partial_x (\xi \circ (f+g))\ne \partial_x (\xi\circ f)+\partial_x (\xi\circ f)=\partial_x (e^{x^2})+\partial_x (e^{y^2})=2xe^{x^2}$$ if $xy\ne 0.$

Comment: @mfl Right. What I was thinking is fundamentally wrong. Need time to think carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I think more than one proof is possible, but that might depend 
on how you define a differential.

One way is to use the chain rule:

Look at $f \times g:M \to \mathbf R^n \times \mathbf R^n, (f \times g)(p)=(f(p),g(p))$, and define also
$\phi: \mathbf R^n \times \mathbf R^n \to  \mathbf R^n, \phi(v,w)=v+w$.

If you accept that: $d(\phi)=\phi$ ($\phi$ is linear) and
$d(f\times g)_{p}(v)=(df_p(v),dg_p(v))$

Then: $\phi \circ (f \times g)=f+g$, and by the chain rule:

$d(f+g)_p(v)=d(\phi)_{(f(p),g(p))} \circ d(f \times g)_p(v)=\phi\big((df_p(v),dg_p(v))\big)=df_p(v)+dg_p(v)$

as required.